# Does anyone know how to get maps working inside an activity group?

Tags: android, android-activity, grid, maps, activitygroup

I have used maps many times before, but this is the first time I have ever tried to use it within an ActivityGroup. I have spent hours pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the maps won't show (just showing the grid) and it turns out that it is simply because the Activity is in an ActivityGroup.

I googled the problem but all found was people asking how and not getting any answers.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get maps working inside an ActivityGroup?

Comment: Look at http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/ .Then try to embed the map.I dont know whether it will work or not

Comment: It might help to post the code you're using to embed the map.

Comment: It's the standard code from the android tutorial. I haven't added any of my own touches because nothing was working. I stripped it down to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActivityGroup manages other activities. An activity with a map has to extend MapActivity (which ActivityGroup obviously does not).

So you can embed an activity that displays a map, but your activity group can't display the map itself.

Comment: I have an activity group with many activities in it. One of them is a MapActivity. They all work fine, but then the MapActivity won't show the map. When I take the map activity out of the activity group, and run it as it's own separate activity, it works fine.

Comment: Are you coming from your standalone MapActivity to your ActivityGroup? You may need to readd the map with new layout params.